# Jreviews site - facebook events integration

Tags: facebook-events

I'm quite new to programming and am really struggling with understanding how to integrate this with my site. I'm hoping there will be some people out there that have been in my shoes!

I have found a number of 'how to's' with regard to adding facebook events, so I have some idea as to the code I need to use but I have no idea where this code needs to go to fit in with the joomla and jreviews documentation.

In addition to that, I don't understand how I code to create events for particular listings on my site (obviously this isn't outlined in the facebook developers guides).

I'm also unsure about which jreviews documents I need to modify so there is a link to fb events attached to my listings

I'm really looking for advice from someone that has experience with jreviews as it's the integrating with jreviews that I'm struggling to figure out.

Here's a link to my site's current location (will be moving it soon to the actual domain) http://superphonics.com.au/loudgamer

TIA for any and all advice!

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

After wrecking my brain trying to figure this out I have turned to a joomla calendar and events extension. Not exactly what we wanted to do, but it is much simpler and with a bit of tweaking, will hopefully function as we desire.

Having trouble linking facebook events to your site? Check out the extensions and plugins already created for your CMS - they might give you just what you need.